# How to check if an IP address is free on a network

Tags: linux, networking, redhat, nmap, ipam

I'm gonna setup a Wireless router for a customer.
They have subnet `10.253.48.0/24`
What can I do to check if the IP `10.253.48.243` is available to set up the router?
I'm on out on a local network at my workplace, the customer's network is `IPVPN`.

I have Access to the Linux console on the out network that can communicate with our customers.
I thought that I could use Nmap command to find out if there's any equipment on the network. 
I tried running the command  `nmap -sP -PE 10.253.253.0/24`
But I dont get the response I'm looking for.
What might I do different to find out if this is an available address?

Comment: As a side note.. I've noticed that whenever I do scans of an entire subnet, I never get good results unless I set the --scan-delay option. I scanned a network here just now using your nmap string which returned 54 hosts. Adding the scan-delay, It brought back 74 hosts, which is closer to what I was expecting.

Comment: Can you just ping the ip address to see if there's a response?  If there's no response its free?

Comment: As a sidenote, use nmap as root. It happens a lot of times that ping is working and nmap is not for this reason.

Answer (score 19):

Ask their network administrator. There is no other way that doesn't risk causing serious problems. It may belong to a machine that's off at the moment.

Comment: Many people have decided that they are too clever for this answer, and even more people have been woken up in the middle of the night as a consequence. Thousands of dollars in labor are lost every year to ignoring this.

Comment: +1. If the customers does not have an allocation plan, he deserves what he gets - namely a clueless contractor setting up a bad ip.